# Wrong redirection of the Magento login is 1.9.3, if the process of placing an order is started

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, redirect

Found a redirection error in the Magento 1.9.3. If you add the product to the shopping cart and begin the process of placing the order, but do not log in to the store, then go to the normal login page and enter any credentials, which leads to a one-page order. It does not matter from which page you came to the login, always redirects to a one-page order. If you delete the item from the shopping cart, it will be redirected once to an empty shopping cart. I see this problem when installing a clean Magento out of the box.

Can someone come across and solve a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution by setting such parameters as

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setBeforeAuthUrl()
```

and

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setAfterAuthUrl()
```

If you specify on the page from which you go to the login form

```
$referer = Mage::helper('core')->urlEncode(Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl());   
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login', array('referer' => $referer)));

Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setAfterAuthUrl(Mage::getUrl('*/*/*'));
```

then redirecting to the previous page will only work if the authorization is successful. By default these two parameters are considered equal